# To write this sentence about a distribution more rigorously

Tags: distribution-theory

I have the sentence at the moment

> Notice that for all $c \in \mathbf{C}$ such that $W(cx) = |c|^{2} Wx$.

which I do not like.

I mean to say that for all $c \in \mathbf C$ the equation is true.

Probably simply

> Notice for all $c \in \mathbf C, W(cx) = |c|^{2} Wx.$

**How can you formulate the sentence about the distribution equation better, when it should stay as a notification only?**

Before I have defined this:

$W: L^{2}(\mathbf R) \to L^{2}(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My offer would be

> Note that $W(cx) = \lvert c\rvert^2 Wx$ for all $c \in \mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

Notice that $A=B$ holds for all $C$.